# XML transformation not working

Tags: slowcheetah, xdt-transform

I have installed the SlowCheetah extension and Nuget Package into my Console App Project. I have used the context menu to add a UAT build configuration and updated a test setting to check that the value is being transformed.

Unfortunately its not, when I try to Preview the Transform via the Context Menu its just showing me the non transformed App.Config.

What steps can I check to see why this extension is not working?

In the main App Config I have specified an appSetting.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="TomTestTransform" value="LOCAL" />
</appSettings>
```

In the App.UAT.config I overwrite it

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="TomTestTransform" value="UAT" />
</appSettings>
```

When I preview the Transform, or build and check the configuration output, its always using the non transformed version. The setting equals LOCAL.

Comment: can you show us the transform files you created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `xdt:` attributes to match and adapt the elements, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
 see the web.comfig examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TomTestTransform"
         value="UAT"
         xdt:Transform="Replace"
         xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

With `xdt:Locator="Match(key)"` you are telling the processor to match the `add` element based on the `key` attribute, and apply `xdt:Transform="Replace"` logic on the whole (located) element.

There is [a msdn entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) available on possible XML transformations, which is also applicable for SlowCheetah transformations, as they are based on the same "technology".

Additionally, the [extension overview](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) has also some good documentation in it!